# question put on hold, reason unclear?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

I have asked a question [What is the one word for people who hate others success?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283970/one-word-for-people-who-hate-others-success).

The question seems to be put on hold, as off topic, can anybody please explain how is this an off topic question?

Comment: I'm not a moderator or a high-rep user, but my feeling is that you should have followed the advice of the first commenter who suggested that you give a sample sentence, and tell us why "jealous" did not fit.  You tried to explain what you meant in your Edit paragraph, but it was hard to follow. Examples are often better than explanations.   "A to B;  You think you are so great because you got an A+  on your paper!  Can't you talk about anything else?"  A is [what] of B?  Why isn't jealous the answer?

Answer (score 6):

The reason the question was put on hold is stated in the post notice:

> Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

The linked page contains more details on how to create a good single-word request question, specifically in the short summary and the checklist at the bottom:

> This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. **You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.**
>
> Describe the intended meaning, connotation, and/or context in as much detail as you can. [Questions that show no research are likely to be closed.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1654/8816)
>
> - Does the question describe exactly in what context you want to use a single word?
> - Does the question specify the criteria for which the suggested word will be accepted?
> - Does the question list which words you didn't like?
> - Does the question show that you searched for a suitable word before asking the question?

The criteria are stringent, because Stack Exchange is a question-and-answer platform where answers are voted on how well they answer the question and where a single answer is acknowledged as best. Single-word-request questions are prone to receiving many answers, so the criteria by which those answers are judged need to be very specific. There are more details about the policy in the [second link above](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1654/8816).

In order to get a good answer (or more than just one), you need to put quite a bit of effort into creating a good question. Other Meta answers have [more on this point](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/does-a-question-which-shows-no-research-no-effort-deserve-a-downvote/5282#5282) and [even more](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed). That is, the question is not off topic, but it's currently not a good question and needs more detail.

When you edit the question to make it fit the tag info, **don't** simply add a subtitle "Edit" followed by additional information. Different versions of the question are already available (click the "Edited" timestamp link). Make the question complete and able to stand on its own.

Once a question is edited following its being placed on hold, it's put into a review queue and the community can vote on reopening it.

Comment: is this a robot generated response!!! pretty much seems so,

Comment: @SouparnoMajumder I can assure you I am a person and each answer I write is crafted individually. But whether or not that's actually the case, a better reaction would be to note the content of the reply and act on it, as it was written in answer to your question and (given its score) it appears to say the right thing. It doesn't really matter whether it was written by a robot, a Martian, a real human member of the community or a dog.